# How can I determine which specific users (UIDs) see and write specific data from rules in the Firebase Realtime Database/Web App?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to determine that specific users (inspectors) see and can work (write) only the cases that are conditioned to their names as inspectors using, if possible, equalTo() in the firebase realtime database rules. Anybody can help me?

I have a similar structure in Firebase:

```
`https://dev-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com/

    ↓idCase
    ↓IdLoans
    -NREvs1K2xaCcjP37ALm
    →LoanNumber: "0001"
    →InspectorName: "John"
    →PropertyAddress: "F-32 Maa St." 
    →Property Condition: "No Data"
        →Property Occupancy: "No Data"

    -NRIs9ibnlVVhI2QtfGt
    →LoanNumber: "0002"
    →InspectorName: "'Jane"
    →PropertyAddress: "D-12 Doo St." 
    →Property Condition: "No Data"
        →Property Occupancy: "No Data"

    -NRJEhrCJAY-QoQFn0wX
    →LoanNumber: "0003"
    →InspectorName: "'Joah"
    →PropertyAddress: "Y-20 Saa St." 
    →Property Condition: "No Data"
        →Property Occupancy: "No Data"

    -NT-HB1Z3cUDG7jvvx2c
    →LoanNumber: "0004"
    →InspectorName: "John"
    →PropertyAddress: "F-34 Maa St." 
    →Property Condition: "No Data"
        →Property Occupancy: "No Data"`
```

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions or help?

```
`{
  "rules": {
  "idCase": {
 "IdLoans": {
  ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid === 'z6Iy8yZFZ1Mf6ZsbfgnF1GlFYtN2' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'John' || auth.uid === 'tMfqfdh6B8hRBrZKT0fjRblUyO13' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'Joah' || auth.uid === 'ynn3RTNQ7CQ6ENIRaXy55AvvFb73' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'Jane')",

  ".write":  "auth != null && (auth.uid === 'z6Iy8yZFZ1Mf6ZsbfgnF1GlFYtN2' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'John' || auth.uid === 'tMfqfdh6B8hRBrZKT0fjRblUyO13' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'Joah' || auth.uid === 'ynn3RTNQ7CQ6ENIRaXy55AvvFb73' && query.orderByChild === 'InspectorName' && query.equalTo === 'Jane')",
    }
  }
}`
```

If this uid === 'z6Iy8yZFZ1Mf6ZsbfgnF1GlFYtN2' login, then can read and write only the cases with the selected condition: equalTo === 'John', and so on with the other users (uid's).